# Ending a Game Based on a Boolean not running any more code afterwards In Java

Tags: java

I'm making a text based version of the game "Are You Smarter than a 5th Grader. It's not quite the same, you are asked a first grade question, and if you miss it, you get one more redemption 1st grade question, and if you miss that one the game is over, but if you get it right you can move on to the 2nd grade question(s).

```
public boolean correct;

public void firstSection() {



    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Main man = new Main();


    System.out.print("The first category is 1st Grade Math. Here is your question... \n What is 5 * 2 + 4 / 2 ?"
            + " \n A. 18 \n B. 15 \n C. 12 \n D. 20");

    String answer;
    answer = scan.nextLine();

    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        System.out.print("Congrtulations you are smarter than a 1st Grader!");
        correct = true;
    } else {
        System.out.print("You missed the first question, but you have one chance to redeem yourself. Here is your 1st"
                + " Grade Social Studies question... \n What is the name of the ship that the pilgrims sailed to America named?"
                + " \n A. Mayflower \n B. Santa Maria \n C. Pinta \n D. Nina");
        answer = scan.nextLine();
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            System.out.print("Congratulations you are smarter than a 1st Grader!");
            correct = true;
        } else {
            System.out.print("You are not smarter than a 1st Grader!");
            correct = false;

        }

    }

}
```

I then have a method, isCorrect:

```
public void isCorrect() {
if(correct) {
    System.out.println("...");
} else {
    System.out.println(" The game is over. You are a loser.");
}
}
```

My main class where I call the methods looks like:

```
    man.firstSection();
    man.isCorrect();

    man.secondSection();
    man.isCorrect();
    ....
```

I pretty much want the game to cut off and not run the 2nd-5th grade questions if the boolean variable is false when isCorrect() is ran after firstSection() but I do not know how to end a game. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many way to do it... Here the simplest example:

```
public void isCorrect()
{
    if(correct)
    {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(" The game is over. You are a loser.");
        System.exit(0); // close the program
    }
}
```

Or add a return statement for isCorrect() (or xSection()) and modify your function who launch the quizz:

```
man.firstSection();
if (!man.isCorrect())
    return 0; // close the function but not the program.

man.secondSection();
if (!man.isCorrect())
    return 0; // close the function but not the program.
....
```

Hint: With that way, you have to create many functions.
The better way is to create only one function who print out the question, and check if the answer is right.

```
public boolean section(String question[][])
{
    // your code here
}
```

After just launch your function in a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't very hard.

To start first we need to fix `isCorrect`

```
public boolean isCorrect() {
if(correct) {
    System.out.println("...");
    return true;
} else {
    System.out.println(" The game is over. You are a loser.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Now just do `if (!man.iscorrecct()) System.exit(0);` after `man.firstsection()` This will exit and terminate the code.

Comment: thank you very much! That works flawlessly, and I have not learned of the System.exit(0); That's why I was having trouble, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can control your loop using your boolean variable.

```
man.firstSection();
man.isCorrect();
while(correct){
man.secondSection();
man.isCorrect();
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Simply modify `isCorrect()` to read

```
public void isCorrect() {
    if(correct) {
        System.out.println("...");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" The game is over. You are a loser.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will exit the program when a question is missed.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(correct){
//do you stuff
}
```

As soon as `correct` becomes `false`, the loop will break and program can be terminated

I hope this is what you want; comment if your question is different

Comment: But it's not the same thing being done all over again... The question is fairly easy to understand

Comment: @Zizouz212 I did check the code and while condition can still be used here. Your way/logic/thinking might just be different :)

Comment: The logic is wrong, the while loop check the condition only at the beginning. You need a condition at each line, not a loop. Also, in this logic, you have to use a do{}while;

Comment: @Celine Sorry, I dont have time to write code right now. But I'll update later how `while` can be used in this case. There are various ways to reach a solution. I can change a few functions and return types and yeah `while(condition)` can be used :)

Comment: @TheUknown Actually, not that I think of it more in-depth, this makes sense. :)