# Making a Window Appear At End of Game

Tags: java, events, event-handling

You can see the summary of my game [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609158/ending-a-game-based-on-a-boolean-not-running-any-more-code-afterwards-in-java/30609321#30609321/%22here%22). I want a window to pop up after it is determined that the player has won or lost, and it would just say "YOU WIN", etc. in big letters. I know how to make a frame, like so:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);

    }

    public Frame() {
        super("Are You Smarter Than a 5th Grader?");
        setSize(600,600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("YOU WIN");
        add(button);
    }
}
```

But I do not know to implement that at all so it will appear at a certain time in my game. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) is the preferred way to show dialogs in a Swing UI.

In your "isCorrect" method:

```
public void isCorrect() {
  if(correct) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win!");
  } else { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose!");
  }
```

}

**UPDATE**

After re-reading that your initial application appears to be a command line application (I thought it was within a GUI), you can simply pass `null` (as edited above) into the JOptionPane method.

Comment: @blazetrooper I get an error stating "The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments(Main, String)" I'm not sure what that really means?

Comment: My apologies - I missed that your'e trying to raise the dialog from a command line application.  in my sample `this` must be a Component (i.e. a window, frame, etc).

Answer (score 0):

define an event, cal it something like onGameDone, raise it when the game is over, and put your frame code in the event handler. for more on events: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/